# How To Access an Array of Objects From Local Storage Using React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I'm new to React and building an application for a project manager that will allow them to manage & share visual timelines with their clients.

When the client logs in I am storing the project details in localStorage where I now want to access them for rendering in the front end.

I can get the full array to display but can't seem to access the individual keys.  I've tried a map function but can't seem to get it to work...

Any help on where I'm going wrong?

```
  // Login Form Submit
  formSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    axios
      .post("/login", data)
      .then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem("projects", JSON.stringify(response.data.projects))
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: true
        })
        this.props.setClient(response.data.client)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ message: error.response.data.message })
      })
  }
```

Thats the login function and saves the project data to the local storage as "projects"

```
class Charts extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      projects: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("projects")
    this.setProjects(data)
  }

  setProjects = projects => {
    this.setState({
      projects: projects
    })
  }
```

Thats the constructor to getItem and setState for projects

```
            <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
              <p className="serviceDescription">
                Project Name:
                <br />
                {this.state.projects}
              </p>
            </Col>
```

This shows I am retrieving the "projects" but as soon as I try to display "project_name" using Dot notation it craps out

[image]

I'm sure this is going to be something obvious im missing as a rookie .. any guidance is totally appreiciated

Thanks in advance
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array, so you cant access it direct via Dot, so you can resolve it by this:

```
{this.state.projects[0].project_name}
```

Note: if you need to print list of projects:
you can use map: `this.state.projects.map(v => v.project_name)`

Comment: unfortunately this hasnt worked - I'm getting  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading'project_name')

Comment: `  46 | <Col lg={6} md={6} sm={12}>
  47 |   <p className="serviceDescription">
  48 |     Project Name:
> 49 |     <br />
     | ^  50 |     {this.state.projects[0].project_name}
  51 |   </p>
  52 | </Col>`

Comment: If you can create sandbox will be better, since base on your image and your code, its must work...Just note, before you call projects, please verify its a JSON parsed object not JSON stringify

Comment: thank you, I got the map function you referenced above to work. I'm just new here so hope its ok to ask :  You referenced making a sandbox - is there a recommended tool for doing that on here?  just for future reference

Comment: You are welcome, yes, you can click and add snippet, but for react running code, Its not recommended from my side...I use this one: https://codesandbox.io/